# Ribbon menu in Windows 8 Desktop apps

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

OK, so for the most part of having Windows 7, implementing the Ribbon menu was a pain. And I really did expect to see full support for it in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC. Since MS seems to want to push it so much.

---

How can I add the Ribbon menu (the original/default/normal one - not some third-party one) to my WinForms OR WPF desktop app for Windows 8 using VS 2012 Ultimate RC?

I have literally searched every single website that looked even remotely related that I could find, but have had no luck whatsoever.

Any help at all is really appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What version of .NET is your project using? (WPF 4.5 includes a Ribbon control.)

Comment: Ah, it's using 4.5. I was hoping to be able to use it with 4.0 and (hopefully also 3.5) - I did see it in the Toolbox in VS 2010 Ultimate and Express Editions, but I don't see it in VS 20_12_ now. I even tried to "Choose Items..." but it didn't appear in the list.

Comment: There are two Riubbon controls from MS: the existing download usable in .NET 4 (no idea if earlier) in `Microsoft.` namespace; and in the box with .NET 4.5. Things like this do not tend to be back ported to earlier frameworks. (Third party component vendors might be a better bet if you must support earlier .NET versions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This msdn link will provide you with the "getting started" info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx)

On that page, download the ribbon project and add it to VS. You can then add it to your project. It works with .NET 4.0 and 4.5, but not 3.5 or below.

Comment: Thank you @Tawnos - I wasn't expecting support for 3.5, I would've loved it though. But on that page you linked to, near the bottom; it says it can be used with .NET 3.5SP1 - I'll see how that goes too.

Comment: Would you know if it's possible to customize the colors of the Ribbon from within XAML/Property pane? From what I can tell now, it only lets you change the background color of the ribbon control. I think I might use Fluent Ribbon instead if I can't get this one styled to my liking.

Comment: Yes, you can change the colors. Click the top of the generated ribbon and you can edit foreground/background colors. The top is the bar right above the tabs.